# Validation Rule Visual Force Page

Tags: visualforce, validation-rule, error-messages

I am trying to display validation rules errors in a VisualForce page I have, but the message isn't showing.

I have the `<apex:pageMessages />` tag inside my page and it works for required fields errors, but nothing works for validation rules.

My controller is a standard one, so I can't do a try/catch block to explicitly write the error to `ApexPages.addMessage()`

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Is the valdiation rule error message set to display at top of page?  If it's set to on field and the field isn't displayed I imagine that could cause this issue.

Comment: @gorav the VR is set to display at top of the page

Comment: This doc, while about custom controllers, appears to indicate that the <apex:messages> component should be used. I know I ran into this recently, can't recall exactly what I did but this seems familiar.  Have you tried that option? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_validation.htm

Answer (score 2):

Validation rules do cause page messages, but only after Visualforce validation and standard validation (e.g. database-required fields). You'll need to get past any Visualforce validation rules and standard validation rules before you can see custom validation errors.

Comment: The thing is if I leave a required field blank, the error message shows. If I put some value on the required field, the page saves correctly. This makes me think that there are no more standard or VF validations when I break the VR on purpose to test this...

Comment: @LuisF Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell why this might be, but I usually use Database.insert/update(record, false) and then check the results of the save before redirecting. VR can be a bit touchy in Visualforce.